# AngularJS Timeout and requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS i do the get requests using the following code

```
myApp.service('ApiCall', function($http, $q){

    this.get_req = function() {

                            var deferred = $q.defer();
                            $http({
                                method: 'GET',
                                url: 'API/RESOURCE',
                                data :params,
                                cache :false
                            }).then(function success(response) {
                                deferred.resolve(response.data);
                              }, function error(error) {
                                deferred.reject(error);
                              });
                            return deferred.promise;
                        };

});
```

This works perfectly but i need to enhance it and have more control over it.

What i want to do is the following

1. once the request fails and set a timer to retry in 5 seconds
2. Then if it fails retry in 10
3. Then 15
4. Then if after those 30 seconds pop up an alert saying what ever i want.

How do i achieve this.

Comment: @pixelbits no that is more like self improvement :)